# i have developed the program and i am facing problems in it

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Kindly give me the access to post quality questions. I am really upset by this action

Comment: show us your attemp/code

Comment: This site isn't for providing entire solutions. It's for helping you to debug problems with existing code. If you have no idea where to start you should spend time with a tutor, or read a tutorial.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. We're here to help people that want to learn (and show some effort), we're *not* here to do your coding for you. Good luck!

Comment: try using `pandas` and the `read_csv` method. Then search for `pandas.crosstab` and see how you get on. If still struggling post the code you have here for help.

Comment: @saniavi007 Stop begging for code, it doesn't make you look very good.

Comment: @COLDSPEED well tried many sources on internet still bit confused so asked here

Comment: @saniavi007 don't be discouraged, this isn't a bad question.  But it helps to show you've put some effort into it.  Have a look at [data manipulation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#data-manipulations) in pandas. Try to word your question so it doesn't come off like you're just asking people to write code for you.  And provide a smaller version of your DataFrame that still illustrates your point but is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by others.

Comment: ' import pandas as pd
    
    
    df = pd.read_csv('ActionsOnly.csv', names=['userId', 'movieId', 'rating'])
    s = df.groupby(['userId', 'movieId']).size()
    
    m = s.unstack()
    
    print(m)'                                                                                                                                                      
i am able to generate the table as the above but not the exact one i wished .
And i want this to write on a `csv` file . I genuinely tried  but was unsuccessful'

Comment: I was trying to do an assignment that time so my questions were totally nasty. Please provide me chance to ask few quality questions in future. Everyone get's another chance. And I have been waiting for 3 years without even trying to create another account. So I think I deserve to be here. Just a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to  pivot the table. Which may give the format you require.

Considering the information you gave as as `ActionsOnly.csv`

```
userId,movieId,rating
18,9,3
32,204,4
49,2817,1
62,160438,4
70,667,5
73,1599,1
73,4441,3
73,4614,3.5
73,86142,4
95,4636,2
103,71,1
118,3769,4
150,4866,2
```

You wan to find out what user rated what movie out of 5.

The `userId` is the index column, the `movieId` becomes the header row and the `rating` is what decides the values. If there is no Value it will display `NaN` or `Not A Number`

```
movie_pivot = movie.pivot_table(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='rating')
```

To Save a file in Pandas to CSV there is a simple command `to_csv`

so

```
movie_pivot.to_csv('ActionsOnly_pivot.csv')
```

Will save to csv.

So the full code you need is:

```
import pandas as pd

movie = pd.read_csv('movies.csv')

movie_pivot = movie.pivot_table(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='rating')

movie_pivot.to_csv('movies_pivot.csv')
```

I also strongly recommend reading about pandas, It is surprisingly easy and logical :)

Comment: if i am writing movie.pivot_table(index='movieId', columns= 'movieId' , values = 'ratings') it shows me a bunch of errors. I want to make movieId- movieId column and want to put the values which i have calculated. but upon writing the above program so many errors are coming

Comment: Did you change the name of the csv? I made a file and called it movies.csv.
If you still get errors.  Write a new question and include the full traceback.  If you post a link here I will help you to debug.

Comment: i have edited the answer just check i am getting the error

Comment: Can you edit your question with the exact code you are running.  Then copy and paste the full error traceback.  I will have a look ands edit my answer to suit the situation.

Comment: This is a different question.. it looks like you wish to create a matrix. You need to start another question as this is now getting confusing.